# How can I match a twitter username with angular ui router

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to be able to match a path like '/@someusername' with angular ui router but can't figure out the regex for it.

What I have are routes like the following

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {url:'/', templateUrl:'/template/path.html'})
.state('author', {url:'/{username:[regex-to-match-@username-here]}'})
.state('info', {url:'/:slug', templateUrl:'/template/path.html'})
.state('entry', {url:'/:type/:slug', templateUrl:'/template/path.html'});
```

I need a bit of regex for the 'author' route that will match @usernames. Currently, everything I try is caught by the 'entry' route.

Comment: `console.log('the-path-to/@username'.match(/(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g))`

Comment: I have updated the description to be more explicit about what I need

Comment: Well, replace `regex-to-match-@username-here` with `(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: I originally tried this but it didn't work. Then I looked at the docs again at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters and saw that the capturing parenthesis had to be removed. Upon removing it, it worked. Thanks @hex494D49 .

Comment: Cool! I should add it as an answer ;)

Comment: Yeah do that and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex below should do the job

```
(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Explanation:

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  @                        '@'
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
)                        end of \1
```

You can use this one, as well

```
(?:@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sL9yE7/1)

Side note: As has been pointer by the OP, capturing parenthesis must not be included if the above is used with AngularJS

Comment: Just from completion according to the angular-ui router docs at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters , the capturing parenthesis must not be included (i.e., @[a-zA-Z0-9]+ instead of (@[a-zA-Z0-9]+) ). Once removed, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your routes in  `config` section:

```
  angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/User/:username', {

}
})
```